# R - For Cycle and Apply function (Quantmod)

Tags: r, quantmod

Hy,

I have this data frame, I want download the data from Yahoo and Calculate Percent Change (Delt function in Quantmod)

```
View(Equity)

  Symbol
1      A
2     AA
3    AAC
```

I made a cycle

```
m<-nrow(Equity)

for (i in 1:m) {

   EquityDF <- Equity[i,]
   Data<-getSymbols(EquityDF,src="yahoo")
   Delt[i]<-apply(EquityDF[,1:5], 2, function(x) Delt(x, k=1)*100)

}
```

But I received this error

```
Error in EquityDF[, 1:5] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I know why this error appear because if I make

```
EquityDF
```

the output it is

```
"A"
```

how can I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `EquityDF` is still a character. To retrieve the corresponding data you must use get: `get(EquityDF)[, 1:5]`

Additionally I'd suggest to call `getSymbols` only once, so that you retrieve all your needed data in a single call, thus your code can be simplified to:

```
Equity <- data.frame(Symbol = c("A","AA","AAC"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
getSymbols(Equity[, 1], src="yahoo")
Delt <- lapply(mget(Equity[, 1]), function(y){
           apply(y[, 1:5], 2, function(x) Delt(x, k=1)*100)})
```

Comment: thks @wici, it's working :) If I do the same for k=2, How can I join the lists? (for exempl de Delt and Delt2) ? Delt2 <- lapply(mget(Equity[, 1]), function(y){
           apply(y[, 1:5], 2, function(x) Delt(x, k=2)*100)})

Comment: What is your expected output of joined lists? maybe you mean this `mapply(list, Delt,Delt2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`?